# Handle exception in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api, xml-parsing

I am calling a Web API from the Web API I am creating. The API I am calling returns the response in XML like

```
<lab:lab uri="https://bh03.org/api/lb/3" xmlns:udf="http://ge.com/ri/userdefined" xmlns:ri="http://ge.com/ri" xmlns:lab="http://ge.com/ri/lab">
<name>GTech</name>
<udf:field type="String" name="Account ID">gt</udf:field>
<website/>
</lab:lab>
```

which I am extracting the value of the Account ID and storing it in the string.

Below the code I am using

```
using (var client_LabURL = new HttpClient())
 {
  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
  Uri Uri_LabURL = new Uri(result_LabURL);
  client_LabURL.BaseAddress = Uri_LabURL;
  client_LabURL.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
  client_LabURL.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
  client_LabURL.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray_Clarity));
  var response_LabURL = client_LabURL.GetAsync(Uri_LabURL).Result;
  string responseString_LabURL = response_LabURL.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
  XDocument new_doc = XDocument.Parse(responseString_LabURL);
  XNamespace ns = "http://ge.com/ri/userdefined";
  string accountID = new_doc.Descendants(ns + "field").FirstOrDefault(field => field.Attribute("name").Value.Equals("Account ID")).Value;
```

But sometimes the API doesnt have the field `<udf>` with Account ID in it.

```
<lab:lab uri="https://bh03.org/api/v2/labs/1302" xmlns:udf="http://ge.com/ri/userdefined" xmlns:ri="http://ge.com/ri" xmlns:lab="http://ge.com/ri/lab">
<name>lsd</name>
</lab:lab>
```

In this scenario I want to create a response like Invalid API Call. So I addded the below code

```
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accountID))
   {
    return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(new { error = "Invalid API Call" }));
   }
```

This doesnot return the response I am expecting when there is not Account ID but instead throws HTTP 500 error. How can I handle this. Any help is greatly appreciaed

Comment: What is the response you are exactly expecting?

Comment: I am creating a response if the string accountID is null or Empty to return the `return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(new { error = "Invalid API Call" }));`

Comment: I mean, what response are you expecting on the *client side*?

Comment: What ever response I am created when there is no `<udf:field type="String" name="Account ID">`

Comment: So, you are expecting a JSON in the response body similar to { error: 'Invalid API call'}?

Comment: Yes  exactly that is what I am creating and want to be sent if there are no udf fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get HTTP status 500, is because you have a `NullReferenceException` exception in your code: you are accessing the `Value` property on the result of `FirstOrDefault` method call, which returns null when no element can satisfy the specified condition.

You can try something like:

```
var accountIdField = new_doc
    .Descendants(ns + "field")
    .FirstOrDefault(field => field.Attribute("name").Value.Equals("Account ID"));

if (accountIdField == null)
{
    return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(new { error = "Invalid API Call" }));
}
```